# Selecting dropdown option is NOT working with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
package com.test.utitlity;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class selectDropdown extends globalVariables {   
    public static void select(String locator, int indexValue) {

     Select select= new Select(common.getObject(locator));
     //select.selectByValue("selectValue");
     System.out.println(indexValue);
     select.selectByIndex(indexValue);   
    }

}
```

It is clicking the dropdown but not selecting the option.. Dropdown is empty.. How to resolve this?? But When I run the debug mode, it is  working as expected. Added wait condition but getting IllegalStateException..

Comment: What does **common.getObject(locator)** return ?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.name("xxx"));

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML code snippet of the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below one and let me know what is the Result.

```
WebDriverWait  Test_Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement Drop_down = Test_Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(common.getObject(locator)));
 List<WebElement> lst2 = Drop_down.findElements(By.xpath(".//option[contains(text(),'Your_Option_Text')]"));
 for (WebElement option : lst2)
    {
        if (!option.isSelected())
               {
                  option.click();
                }
    }
```

Comment: Changed my Code as you said!!! Still it is going to that option but not selecting that option..Tried Tab option same.. it is giving blank..Could not able to guess, why it is not working.. Other dropdowns are working perfectly